# Text underline margin

Tags: css, text, margin

I want to set distance between top edge of document and line of text (the same line that underline would be) for example for 200px, no metter how big the text is (even if text would be that big that it would go out of top edge of document)

[image]

Red line shows bottom line of text and top edge of document, I want constant distance between them. Text size may be various

http://jsbin.com/azanuw/9/edit - example - how to make their bottom lines to has same top position.

Comment: What have you tried?  It looks like display:inline-block and top padding or margin on the text should do what you need?

Comment: Thats not do the thing for me (maybe Im doing something wrong). I will explain it that way: our page is checkered notebook and you have to write header on line nr 5, subheader on line nr 7, content on line nr 9, no matter how big your letters are.

Comment: Then you want a fixed height block element that the text goes inside of

Answer (score 0):

Create a div in part of red line. Give padding-top:200px; for this div.

Comment: Extra syntax is generally frowned upon. If you wanted this approach, would be better to make the block-level element have an absolute position with `top:200`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `em` spacing for margin. The `em` height is the vertical height of the letter 'm'. That way when the the text size changes, the spacing towards the top will be vertically proportionate to the size of the text.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/azanuw/9/edit the same thing. How to make their bottom lines at the same top position.

Answer (score 0):

try this [demo](http://jsbin.com/azanuw/3/edit)

whatever be the font size the text bottom will be 200px from top

**CSS**

```
body {background:#000; margin:0;}
.topNav {color:#fff; height:200px; border:solid 1px #f00; position:relative; }
.text {position:absolute; bottom:0px;font-size:20px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="topNav">
    <div class="text">Some text goes hear</div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/azanuw/9/edit I've edited your code. changed text sizes. That can be clearly seen that their 'underlines' has different distance from top edge. (if alphabet wouldnt have letters like g,p,j etc with bottom part it would propably be ok)